# How to make a directoriy with subfolders using NSIS?

Tags: installation, nsis, setuptools

I have a .NSI script file and want to make a directory structure in my installation path. Next to my .NSI file I have a /data folder containing all my executables and libraries, but I need a MAIN folder with subfolders too, how can I create folders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create folders with the `CreateDirectory` instruction:

```
CreateDirectory "$InstDir\Foo\Bar\Baz"
```

If you already have a directory tree with files on your source system then you can use the `File` instruction with the `/r` switch:

```
SetOutPath "$InstDir"
File /r "c:\mystuff\data\*.*"
; Note: c:\mystuff\data is not the same as c:\mystuff\data\*.*, try both to see the difference
```

Comment: we did it same time :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

I created a /data folder containing the desired structure and then use this code:

```
File /r "data\*"
```